# Problem with integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I evaluate this integral?

$$
\int{x^{3}\,{\rm d}x \over \left(x - 1\right)^{2}\sqrt{x^{2} + 2x + 4}}$$

I would be grateful for any tips.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I am not very familiar with maths related vocabulary in English.

Comment: Well, you can mean two things: evaluate usually means plugging in values. But for this we would need the borders of the integral. Or you could mean that you want to know the parent function. Which one is it?

Comment: @MarcinMajewski No need to apologize. Most native English speaking students don't know the correct terminology either. =p

Comment: I would like to know the parent function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $x^2+2x+4=(x+1)^2+(\sqrt3)^2,$  using [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution)

let us set $x+1=\sqrt3\tan\psi$ and assuming $0<\psi<\frac\pi2$ so that $\sec\psi,\tan\psi>0$

$$I=\int\frac{x^3}{(x-1)^2\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}}dx=\int\frac{(\sqrt3\tan\psi-1)^3}{(\sqrt3\tan\psi-2)^2\sqrt3\sec\psi}\sqrt3\sec^2\psi d\psi$$

$$I=\int\frac{(\sqrt3\tan\psi-2+1)^3}{(\sqrt3\tan\psi-2)^2}\sec\psi d\psi$$

$$=\int\left((\sqrt3\tan\psi-2)+3+\frac3{\sqrt3\tan\psi-2}+\frac1{(\sqrt3\tan\psi-2)^2}\right)\sec\psi d\psi$$

$$=\sqrt3\int\tan\psi\sec\psi d\psi+\int\sec\psi d\psi+3\int\frac{\sec\psi}{\sqrt3\tan\psi-2}d\psi+\int\frac{\sec\psi}{(\sqrt3\tan\psi-2)^2}d\psi$$

The first two integral are too easy to be described

For the third, $\displaystyle\int\frac{\sec\psi}{\sqrt3\tan\psi-2}d\psi=\int\frac1{\sqrt3\sin\psi-2\cos\psi}d\psi$ asking for [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)

For the fourth  $\displaystyle I_4= \int\frac{\sec\psi}{(\sqrt3\tan\psi-2)^2}d\psi=\int\frac{\cos\psi}{(\sqrt3\sin\psi-2\cos\psi)^2}d\psi$

We can write $\displaystyle\cos\psi=A\frac{d(\sqrt3\sin\psi-2\cos\psi)}{d\psi}+B(\sqrt3\sin\psi-2\cos\psi)$ so that

$\displaystyle I_4$ becomes $\displaystyle A\int\frac{d(\sqrt3\sin\psi-2\cos\psi)}{(\sqrt3\sin\psi-2\cos\psi)^2}+B\int\frac1{\sqrt3\sin\psi-2\cos\psi}d\psi $

Now solve for $A,B$

Comment: @MarcinMajewski, my pleasure. But I hope, there should be an easier method

Comment: @labbhattachrjee I think I figured it out, but there is nothing to be excited about. The first Euler substitution method would be slightly easier.

Comment: I don't think Weierstrass is necessary for the third integral.  You should be able to rewrite the denominator as $A\cos(\psi+B)$ leaving the integral of a secant.

Comment: Now that I think of it, the fourth can be done in the same manner.

Comment: @Mike, I think Weierstrass  really simplifies $$\frac1{A\cos x+B\sin x}$$ then use $$\tan y=\frac{\sin2y}{1+\cos2y}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide an alternate method of solving the last 2 integrals from lab bhattacharjee's answer.  The first step is to rewrite

$$\sqrt3\sin\psi-2\cos\psi\text{  as  }A\cos(\psi+B)=A\cos\psi\cos B-A\sin\psi\sin B$$

So we have

$$A\cos B=-2,A\sin B=-\sqrt3$$
$$\tan B=\frac{\sqrt3}2,B=\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt3}2$$
$$A^2=(-2)^2+(-\sqrt3)^2=7$$
$$A=-\sqrt7$$

So the third integral

$$\int\frac{d\psi}{\sqrt3\sin\psi-2\cos\psi}=-\frac{\sqrt7}7\int\sec(\psi+\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt3}2)d\psi$$

which is a straightforward integral of a secant.

As for the fourth integral,

$$\int\frac{\cos\psi d\psi}{(\sqrt3\sin\psi-2\cos\psi)^2}=\frac17\int\frac{\cos\psi d\psi}{\cos^2(\psi+\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt3}2)}$$

$$\theta=\psi+\tan^{-1}\frac{\sqrt3}2$$

I'm out of time for now (I'll probably come back to it later), but if you expand the cosine in the numerator, you should end up with a $\sec\theta$ term and a $\sec\theta\tan\theta$ term, both of which can be easily integrated.